# yml fixtures paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What's the best way to specify Paperclip field in the yml file for tests? One of the possible solutions is outlined in [Fixtures with Paperclip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728391/fixtures-with-paperclip) but I am not sure how to get it to work.

Here's what I have:

model.yml

```
one:
  id: 2
  image: image.jpg

two:
  id: 2
  image: image.jpg
```

model

```
class Doodle < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :image
  has_attached_file :image,
                :styles => {:thumb => "100x100>"},
                :storage => :s3,
                :s3_credentials => S3_CREDENTIALS
```

Cheers, 
Andrei

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the Yaml file in the `config` directory, and use it in your model like this:

```
class Doodle < ActiveRecord::Base

  s3_config_file = File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 
                                          *%w[.. .. config cloud.yml]))

  attr_accessible :image
  has_attached_file :image,
            :styles => {:thumb => "100x100>"},
            :storage => :s3,
            :s3_credentials => s3_config_file
```